# The monomials not inside $\operatorname{in}_<(I)$ form a K-basis inside the quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, vector-spaces, ideals, monomial-ideals

> Given the quotient ring $S/I$, where $S=K[x_1,...,x_n]$ is a polynomial ring and $I$ is an ideal. I need to show that for any monomial $x^u:=x_1^{u_1}\cdots x_n^{u_n}$, if the monomial is not inside $\operatorname{in}_<(I):=\langle\{\operatorname{in}_<(f)\mid f\in I\}\rangle$, then the monomial is part of a $K$-basis for the vector space $S/I$.

I've already shown that $S/I$ is a vector space.

I assumed that $x^v\notin\operatorname{in}_<(I)$, which implies $x^v\notin I$. Since $S/I=\{s+I|s\in S\}$, and $x^v\in S$, $0\in I$ (can I say that $0\in I$, or is that not a general case with ideals), then $(x^v +0)\in S/I$. So for the monomials $x^{v_1},...,x^{v_m}$ with the same property as $x^v$, I need to show that they are all linearly independent in $S/I$ and span $S/I$. However, I'm struggling on proving this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the set of $x^{v}$ that are not in $\operatorname{in}_{<}(I)$.

Linear independence is easy - if a linear combination $F$ of the set is zero in $S/I$ then when considered as an element of $S$ we have $F\in I$ so one of them is in $\operatorname{in}_{<}(I)$, contradiction.

Spanning is harder. Consider the set $H$ of non zero $f\in S$ that are non zero in $S/I$ and are not a linear combination of our set. Then in each $f\in H$ there is some maximal term $x^u$ w.r.t < which is not in our set, so is in $\operatorname{in}_{<}(I)$. If $H$ is non empty we can take the $f$ which has the minimal one of these.  We know then that there is some $g\in I$ with $\operatorname{in}_{<}(g)=x^u$. Taking the correct multiple of $g$ from $f$ gives polynomial in $H$ which has a smaller maximal element than $f$, contradiction. So $H$ is empty, so our set spans $S/I$.

Comment: I'm having some trouble understanding your proof for spanning, for the set $H$ of elements non-zero in $S/I$, these elements cannot be in $I$, right? but then what do you mean by "and are not a linear combination of our set".

Comment: Correct, they're not in $I$. I used 'our set' to refer to the set of monomials we want to show span $S/I$

Comment: @Robert I'm sorry to dig this up, but how do you know f minus a multiple of g is in H?

Comment: @chilliBeanDream No problem, nice to see an old answer get attention! A non-zero element of $S$ is in $H$ if it is non-zero in $S/I$ and not a linear combination of the $x^v$ in the answer in $S/I$. But $f=f-hg$ when working in $S/I$ so so $f$ is in $H$ if and only if $f-gh$ is in $H$. The important point is that membership of $H$ is defined by properties in $S/I$

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up. I was trying to show that f - gh was not a linear combination of the set

Comment: @RobertChamberlain Where is the contradiction for the linearly independent bit?

Comment: @Bob The contradiction is that $F$ is a linear combination of monomials $x^v$ that are not in $in_<(I)$, but if $F\in I$ then $in_<(F)\in in_<(I)$. I think in your second question you're referring to the second line of the spanning part of the proof? I mean in each $f\in H$ - I'll edit the answer, thanks